# mapping math function using artificial neural network

Tags: machine-learning

I recently started learning about neural networks, I'm trying to modelate some economical indicators using neural networks. For example:

ROC = [(Close - Close n periods ago) / (Close n periods ago)] * 100

I'm pressuming input layer will contain closing price, but what about activation function in hidden layer?

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should experiment with a few types of non-linear functions (tanh/sigmoid) and see which fits your data better.

Comment: I thought that the output of sigmoid function will be 1 or 0? I'm trying to get solution which is real value of the equation, can I get that with sigmoid?

Comment: It will be within 0 and 1, not precisely 0 or 1.